# How to get img url and file url in jquery in wordpress plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am creating a plugin in wordpress. I am trying to get the img url and file url in jQuery. Code below. What did I do wrong?

```js
$('.result_tag')
  .append('<img src="plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'remove_sign.png'" >');

$.post("plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'delete.inc.php'", {
    tag : text,/
  },
  function(data){
      $("#result_tag").html(data); 
});
```

Comment: The quoting looks broken in your first line - haven't you got nested single-quotes?

Answer (score 2):

supposing you are working in a `.php` file, you are missing the php tags `<?php ?>`

```
$('.result_tag')
  .append('<img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'remove_sign.png' ?>" >');

$.post("<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'delete.inc.php' ?>", {
    tag : text,/
  },
  function(data){
      $("#result_tag").html(data); 
});
```

just change

```
'<img src="plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'remove_sign.png'" >'
```

to

```
'<img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'remove_sign.png' ?>" >'
```

Comment: I had tried those way, add <?php echo ;?>, but still no luck.

Comment: jquery, so far, I figure out a way to do it by hidden input, and call it by jquery. It is OK. But how come in jquery, it cannot call the url, I guess php load in server side, jquery load in client side, so put dir_url in jquery, it will call the client side user url, am I right?

Comment: is this code in a `.js` file or in a '.php' file? are you getting any javascript error? are you using Firebug or something like that where you can debug the ajax call or js erros?